# Looking for nouns that describe someone who doesn't ascend/go to heaven

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm currently looking for nouns that describe someone who won't go to heaven or someone who was given an opportunity to move on but refused.

I'm currently writing a novel that involves fallen angel characters, and I thought it would be cool to give this group a compelling title.

> Not all embraced the true faith. The ___________ trod a different path.

Comment: hello and welcome. please note the requirement at the tag for single-word requests: *. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.*

Comment: Old-Ford-car-driver.

Comment: 'The damned' is traditional. (I've always wondered about premises like this. Surely Angels have no need for faith - they see it as reality; and the damned just don't like it.)

Comment: @simonatrcl, [James 2:19 You believe that God is one. Good for you! Even the demons believe that — and shudder.](https://biblehub.com/james/2-19.htm)

Comment: Do you have in mind somebody who **disbelieves** the teachings of the relevant religion (as simonatrlc points out, it is hard to see how that would apply to angels) or somebody who believes them, but nevertheless rejects the salvation that the religion offers, perhaps in the manner of the main character in *Der Himmel über Berlin* (*Wings of Desire*)?

Comment: Your question needs to be much more specific than it is. You say *X or Y*, but which it is determines the question and the answer. Are they somebody who Heaven *rejected* or somebody who *refused* to go to Heaven (if such a thing is even possible)? Are they still alive or have they died?

Answer (score 1):

Words that come to mind:

- **heretic**: someone who asserts his adherence to the true faith, but who is rejected by true believers for his deviations from it
- **apostate**: someone who has forsaken his religion
- **renegade**: can be the same as apostate
- **infidel**: someone who rejects the true faith

I have specifically chosen several words that are often used pejoratively by those who are convinced their own religion is the only true one, as it seems there characters are to receive a pejorative name in your novel.

Answer (score 1):

The **damned**. Discussions around Calvinism and predestination often focus on the division between the *elect* (the *saved* or *chosen*) who are going to heaven and the *damned* who are not.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_in_Calvinism